# Access Control: Missing Authentication (Fortify)

Tags: fortify

I am working on one fortify issue which says that any area of the website or web application that contains sensitive information or access to privileged functionality such as remote site administration requires authentication before allowing access:

> The URL ~FullURL~ has failed this policy

Comment: Please let me know in case if anyone needs more information

Comment: From Ozgur_Oz: Is that a Fortify data flow rule?
Could you copy the Fortify description?
Which language are you scanning?
Are you using an MVC pattern? Which one?